# Cannot query SNMP agent from hosts in the local network

Tags: linux, snmp, snmpd

I'm trying to configure SNMP (net-snmp) daemon on my OpenSuse box. 
Agent works on 192.168.1.3 address, and I'd like to send requests from other hosts in 192.168.1.0/24 network. My snmpd.conf file has the following community settings (I'm using SNMPv2):

```
rwcommunity private 192.168.1.0/24
rocommunity public
```

I can execute queries on both communities from localhost (192.168.1.3) successfully. However, every time I try to run the same query from host 192.168.1.2 I get timeout.

For example:

> snmpwalk -v 2c -c private 192.168.1.3
>   .1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2 
>  snmpwalk -v 2c
>   -c public 192.168.1.3 .1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2

executed from 192.168.1.3 machine gives appropriate results.
The same queries executes from 192.168.1.2 gives timeout.

SNMP agent is bound to all network interfaces, thus, it's also visible from 192.168.1.2:

> $ sudo nmap -sU 192.168.1.3 -p 161
>
> Starting Nmap 5.00 ( http://nmap.org )
>   at 2011-06-23 18:42 CEST Interesting
>   ports on 192.168.1.3: PORT    STATE
>   SERVICE 161/udp open|filtered snmp

Any hints appreciated,
Piotr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are there any other com2sec or rw/rouser lines in your configuration?

Is iptables enabled on either the source or destination host that would prevent UDP traffic?

Comment: You were right, it was some mistakenly added firewall policies on my network router. SNMP configuration was fine. Thanks.